# Sort Importrange a Column

Tags: sorting, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to sort from an importrange. I was able to do it on a descending order but whenever I sort a new column on ascending, it wont return any data or just blank.

Here's the format I have so far:
Desc: =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Google sheet url","Raw!A2:A") , "select * order by Col1 desc")

Asc: =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Google sheet url","Raw!A2:A") , "select * order by Col1 asc")-this seems not to work.

Your ideas/help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any chance the data is at bottom of the query_formula column since the ascend sort has stacked the blank cells on top followed by data cells lastly!